# Drupal 7 PHP Filter not evaluating

Tags: php, drupal, filter, drupal-7, format

It seems I cannot add PHP to my content and cannot figure out what needs to be changed. Looking at the source it gets passed as plain text and Firefox hides it by adding

What I've done:

- I've created a new text format, enabling the PHP Evaluator and
  allowing the administrator.
- I've given the permissions to
  Administrator for "PHP Filter".
- I've given the permission to
  administrator for "Use the PHP code text format"

I am using CKeditor but under the CKeditor configuration it is only enabled for "Filtered HTML". This still happens if I disable the CKeditor module.

Are there any known modules that break the PHP filter? I've been Googling for hours, and I've read every stack overflow I could about this but they all tell you to do the above 3 steps.

** I just tried making a Block that had PHP in it and that works fine. Its only on content WebPages.

Comment: what's the exact problem? You get printed all your code? Showing some code and output might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your filters and check if your PHP filters 'evaluate PHP' is checked. It needs to be checked to having it working.